# How to draw points with bright colors in an image with Pillow/PIL library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm implementing a basic crowd dynamic software. At each timestep, all people inside a rectangular area with exits is evolved in the direction pointed by the model. The output at each timestep shall be printed to an image. I did not have big issues in drawing the area as a rectangle and the people as points, but now I'd need to give each point a color based on the speed of the person it represents.

```
if(vel == 3):
    draw.point((xp, yp), fill='blue')

elif vel == 2:
    draw.point((xp, yp), fill='red')

elif vel == 1:
    draw.point((xp, yp), fill='green')
```

I get the following jpg file:
[image]

As you can see, it is very difficult to tell the difference between each point. 
Do you have hints in how to make the colors much brighter? Also suggestions on different ways to "output" the results are  welcome.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try drawing a 9x9 square, instead of just 1 pixel? It seems that the anti-aliasing or smoothing makes the colors less vibrant. Another path to try is to output to a lossless PNG rather than a JPEG, or even a higher quality JPEG.

Comment: @advance512 : Thank you for your hints. Using a square of 9 pixels would require an important change in the algorithm logic, since the movement unit is set to one pixel.
I tried to set max jpg quality, but I got the best results by using PNG.. Thank you then

Comment: Great, happy to hear it helped you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the anti-aliasing or smoothing makes the colors less vibrant. One path to try is to output to a lossless PNG rather than a JPEG, or even a higher quality JPEG. Another is to use a 9x9 pixel square, that'll be less affected by the smoothing.